# Give one variable a number value and string value?

Tags: lua

I am trying to have one variable that has a number value as well as a string value.

I am coding in Lua and I don't know how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

[Tables.](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) They are like a filing cabinet where you can store as many values as you want and retrieve them given some kind of "key". In Lua, the key can be any type, but the most common key is going to be a numerical index or a string.

Given:

```
local age = 30  -- your number values
local name = 'Fred' -- your string value
```

There's a tons of different ways we can structure that in Lua:

```
local person = { age = 30, name = 'Fred' )
print(person.age, person.name)
```

---

```
local person = { 'Fred', 30 }
print(person[1], person[2])
print(unpack(person))
```

---

```
local person = { Fred = 30 }
print(person.Fred)
```

---

```
local person = { [30] = 'Fred' }
print(person[30])
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: `print(person[0], person[1])` - 0-based table indices by default is a dream of many Lua programmers )

Answer (score 1):

So if i use..

```
coal = { name = "Coal", value = 80 }
```

I can then do this?

```
    userInput = read()

    if userInput == coal.name then
        fuelUse = coal.value        
    end
```